# Get current row when edit button clicked in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

in my `DataGrid` the last column is a `TemplateColumn` that has an Edit Button, the current implementation is that the user needs to check a checkbox beside the row and then click the edit button, obviously, this is nonsense, so isn't there a way to get the current row when I click the related edit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "current row" is the `DataContext` of the `Button` so you could cast the `sender` argument and the `DataContext` property:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button:
    YourClass selectedRow = button.DataContext as YourClass;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for getting the selected row:
Suppose this is the template column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="Button_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgDatagrid}">Details</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Provide the element name as the name of your datagrid as the command parameter and in your code behind or view model use the following:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid datagrid = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter as DataGrid;
    var selectedRow = datagrid.SelectedItem;
    var selectedIndex = datagrid.SelectedIndex;
}
```

This way you can get the selected item or the row.

Comment: selectedRow is null, and selectedIndex is -1

Comment: Please make sure your CommandParameter is not null. It is working perfectly fine at my end.